# Swift database retrieve data

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

how can I retrieve all "author" from all subcategorys?

I have database structure:
[image]

And I want to get all author's from books, films, serials,...

Сategories will be added and subcategorys will grow too.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a list of all authors under each category.

Comment: And how then I can use it with each category?

Comment: Whether it is possible to pull out of all?

Comment: or, have a node "Authors" at the same level as Category, which is a list of [AuthorName : Category] items. Keep it in sync with the data under Category using cloud functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [Denormalizing](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) as well as [Structuring](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) your Firebase data.

In this case you data is probably structured too deeply to get out of it what you want.

First thing to do is to add a node to handle authors

```
authors
  author_id_0
     name: "Charles Dickens"
     bday: "the birthday"
     staus: "inactive"
  author_id_1
     name: "Robert Heinlein"
     bday: "the birthday"
     staus: "inactive"
```

Then update your book to to refer to that author:

```
category
  book
    book_id_0
       author: author_id_0
       name: "some book name"
       quotes
          quote_id_0: "some quote"
          quote_id_1: "another quote"
```

Now it's easy to get a list of all of your authors and you could add other information about them as well - birth date, active or inactive etc.

Your structure could probably be further flattened by breaking out the quotes

```
quotes
  for_book_id_0
      quote_id_0: "some quote"
      quote_id_1: "another quote"
```

That would make the quotes much more queryable.